# Set datepicker default date

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to set the default dates of two text boxes so that they are populated when the page opens. I want the searchStart to be the 01/01/ of the current year and the end to default to today. This is my code and its not working:

```
(<any>$('#searchStart')).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', defaultDate: '01/01/' + getFullYear() });
(<any>$('#searchEnd')).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' defaultDate: new Date()  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current date, you can do `var theDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date());` and make your input `.val(theDate)`.

For the other one:

```
var theYear = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy', new Date());
$('input').val('01/01/' + theYear);
$('input').datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
    defaultDate: '01/01/' + theYear
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/69j7Y/)